# How to create and populate a local SQLite db with API json data?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm creating a `Xamarin.Forms` application that will consume data from an API Rest that I created in C#.

What I'm trying to do is to store all `JSON` data returned from the `API` to a local `SQLite` DB, then I'll use that data in all the application interfaces.

Till here all is well:

```
public async void GetProduct()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("localhost/api/products");
        var product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(response);

        lvProducts.ItemsSource = propriedade;

    }
```

What I want is to populate a table in local DB instead o populating a `ListView`.

Do you have some simple implementable code that I can use to reach this goal?

Comment: Have you read the docs on using local databases?  It would help if you did and then explained what **specific** parts you don't understand or were getting errors from.  There are also many sample apps on using sqlite available from the Xamarin site.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is store the data and display it (as your post implies) then you should just use **[monkey-cache](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/monkey-cache)** to do the heavy lifting. It's designed specifically to solve that problem.

Otherwise, you'll need to look at implementing local data access and writing your own data access code. [This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases) will get you started with that.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want is to populate a table in local DB instead o populating a ListView.

According to your description, you have get List using Api, now you want to create local sqlite table and populate this list in this table.

Firstly, you need to install **sqlite-net-pcl** by Nuget package.

Then create one sqlite DataBase and  Product table, using following code:

```
 public void createtable()
    {
        var fileName = "Productdata.db3";
        var documentPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var path = Path.Combine(documentPath, fileName);

        connection = new SQLiteConnection(path);
        connection.CreateTable<Product>();


    }
```

Finally, foreach List data and insert data in Sqlite Product Table.

```
 private void Btn4_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(response);
        foreach(Product p in products)
        {
            Product prod = new Product();
            prod.productname = p.productname;
            var data = connection.Table<Product>();

            var d1 = data.Where(x => x.productname == prod.productname).FirstOrDefault();
            if (d1 == null)
            {
                connection.Insert(prod);
                Console.WriteLine("Sucessfully Added");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Already Mail id Exist");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the product class:

```
public class Product
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string productname { get; set; }

}
```

Here is the article about insert data in Local sqlite database, you can take a look:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-sqlite-in-xamarine-forms-application/